# How do you create y and x labels when plotting multiple histograms at once?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

So I wrote this code to plot data into 5 different histograms in 1 output:

```
time = df['elapsed_time']
dist = df['distance']
avespd = df['Average Speed']
avepow = ['Average Power']
tss = df['TSS']
df1 = df[['elapsed_time','distance', 'Average Speed', 'Average Power', 'TSS']]
df1.hist(density=0,histtype='stepfilled',figsize=(16,18))


plt.show()
```

The output was:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjXk8.png)

I've tried using:

```
plt.ylabel('Rides',fontsize=15)
```

to add a label to atleast one of the histograms, but it doesn't work.
What I want to do is to label all the histograms with the y label being 'Rides', and the x-label corresponding to the values in df1. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by creating a figure first and then apply your data on this figure, like this:

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  #ploting library
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches # ploting legend


## Create the figure
title = 'My plots'
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=21, fontweight='bold')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(16, 8, (1,128))

# Legends
orange_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='darkorange', label='Rides')
ax1.legend(handles=[orange_patch])

# Add Data to the plot
df1.hist(density=0, histtype='stepfilled', ax=ax1)
```

Comment: Hey benoit, for some reason I get the error 
"UserWarning: To output multiple subplots, the figure containing the passed axes is being cleared
  exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)"
I am currently trying to execute the code on my jupyter notebook

Comment: Okay, si using my method it appears that you have to create a subplot for each of your graph. How many of them do you have?   Is it a recurring action that you do and the number of plot change?